# Failed connect to localhost:7474; Connection refused. Where is the neo4j-server.properties file?

Tags: r, neo4j, r-neo4j

I am trying to start my graph from Rstudio on Mac OSx, installed RNeo4j via devtools on (for R version 3.1.2)
"startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")"
and i received the following error:

> "Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    Failed connect to
>   localhost:7474; Connection refused"

It looks like it is an Error code: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
searching online, they recommend to modify conf/neo4j-server.properties file.
But cannot seem to find the file to correct it.

Comment: Also, no firewall running?

Comment: How did you install Neo4j?  The location of the `conf/neo4j-server.properties` file would be different depending on what you used

Comment: Hi, I installed via Rneo4J (devtools). My guess is that is not working because of the firewall at the company, but not sure how work around it. Thats why i tried to change the server properties file. but cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Are you able to open the Neo4j browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Neo4j 2.2?  If so, you might need to specify the username and password (which you can set by going to `localhost:7474` in your browser if you haven't already).

Comment: He would get an unauthorized error if that were the case.

Comment: I suppose that's true.  I was thinking of the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` as a general connection exception which was hiding was was below, but it's probably more of a network issue rather than a successful HTTP request with an unsuccessful result

Answer (score 5):

check `conf/neo4j.conf`, there is one line:

```
# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting to bolt://127.0.0.1:7687 
or 
See the log in $NEO4J_HOME/logs/neo4j.log file. There should be some error showing the exact ip neo4j has hosted to.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had changed the name of my local IP address from `localhost` to `localhost.dev`

To see your settings:

`cat /etc/hosts`

My one looks like this

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost.dev
127.0.0.1   api.localhost.dev
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you prefer to connect to neo4j without authentication, it is easy to change the default. The corresponding documentation for version 2.2.1 is [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/security-server.html)

Make the following change in the file conf/neo4j-server.properties file:

```
# dbms.security.auth_enabled=true
# 
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

Comment: where is the file? i cannot seem to find the file anywhere